# Multiple JavaScript countdowns

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, countdown

```
<?php wpsc_start_category_query(array('category_group'=>get_option('wpsc_default_category'), 'show_thumbnails'=> 1)); ?>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    countdown('countdown<?php wpsc_print_category_id(); ?>');
}
var interval;

var seconds = 5;
function countdown(element) {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        var el = document.getElementById(element);
        if(seconds == 0) {
         el.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";                    
         clearInterval(interval);
         return;
        }
        el.innerHTML = seconds + ' seconds remaining';
        seconds--;
    }, 1000);
}
</script>

<div id='countdown<?php wpsc_print_category_id(); ?>'></div>
<?php wpsc_end_category_query(); ?>
```

my task it display such countdown for every wp query.
the problem is that it only displays for the last queried object. My guess is that's becaus   window.onload, but I cant think any alternative

Any Help?

Comment: where are the other wp queries? you need to either add the old data for each new request or use ajax to load the new ones in - not entirely sure what the wp stuff does, do you have an example of your page?

Comment: WP queries categories which expire after some time. with the published time + 1 week Seconds I want to implement counter for every such category. what you mean by old data?

Comment: maybe I need unnamed functions or whatsoever like $(function(){});

Comment: im trying to work out where the other timers come in to it. is that code generated for every group you have?

Comment: this is query
the code between start_category_query and end_category_query repeats.
WP stuff is total rubbish.

I just want somethign like this: http://www.plndr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't 100% understand what the WP stuff does so this might just be total rubbish!

My code has 2 parts, a part to use in-place of your current code, the template, and a portion of code to have in your page `<head>`, the countdown function.

There's also a function to convert seconds into days,hours,mins and seconds should your interval not be constant at 5 seconds in the future.

The countdown function will update all countdowns that are set-up by the template code.

Hope it helps :)

**Update**

My code does not edit or delete anything on your server, obviously named my variable a little too close to home for you :) As my comment says, the `delete` call only removes the counter from the list holding information about the counters, removing the delete statement will leave finished counters in the list (not a problem, just less efficient as they are iterated over when `tick()` gets called)

I will try to describe what my code does at the bottom so you can understand better what is going on.

WPSC Template

```
<?php   wpsc_start_category_query(array('category_group'=>get_option('wpsc_default_category'), 'show_thumbnails'=> 1)); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!wpsc_categories) { wpsc_categories = {}; }
wpsc_categories['countdown_<?php wpsc_print_category_id(); ?>'] = 5; // this value is the countdown in seconds
</script>
<div id="countdown_<?php wpsc_print_category_id(); ?>"></div>
<?php wpsc_end_category_query(); ?>
```

If you want a 1 week countdown and for the countdown to persist over page views (so it does not reset to 1 week when you refresh) you will need to store a counter start date on your server, calculate the difference between then and now (with php) and use that in-place of 5 ( I guess that is what you planned on doing anyway though! )

Countdown Function - This should be included in the header of your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var wpsc_categories = [];

// the following function will update all counters using one timer (hopefully)
function tick() {
    var element;
    for (category in wpsc_categories) {
        if (wpsc_categories.hasOwnProperty(category)) {
            element = document.getElementById(category);
            if (wpsc_categories[category] == 0) {
                element.innerHTML = "countdown over!";
                delete wpsc_categories[category];
            } else {
                // MODIFIED THIS LINE, SEE NOTE
                //element.innerHTML = formatTime(wpsc_categories[category]--);
                element.innerHTML = formatTime(wpsc_categories[category]);
                wpsc_categories[category] -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
    //return setInterval(tick, 1000); //this line is bad :D
}

var interval = setInterval(tick, 1000) // start it running

// return formatted time from seconds (if required)
function formatTime(seconds) {
    var numdays = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
    var numhours = Math.floor((seconds % 86400) / 3600);
    var numminutes = Math.floor(((seconds % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
    var numseconds = ((seconds % 86400) % 3600) % 60;
    return (numdays>0?numdays+" days ":"")+(numhours>0?numhours+" hours ":"")+(numminutes>0?numminutes+" minutes ":"")+(numseconds>0?numseconds+" seconds":"")
}
</script>
```

**Note**

I changed the way the remaining time is updated to make it a little more clear. I used a decrement operator `--` which can be a little annoying.

**Description**

Your original template copied a large block of code for every category, including the countdown code and the call that invokes it, which is why only the last categories timer was working. `window.onload` was being overwritten by each subsequent category.

Yes you could have used an anonymous function to start the function rolling and it should have worked, but its probably not the best solution.

Now for my code

you had a question about `if (!wpsc_categories) { wpsc_categories = {}; }` wpsc_categories is an object that stores information about counters. this checks to see if the object exists and creates it if it does not so that the next like can add information about a counter.

In the browser, your client would get the following for 3 example groups.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!wpsc_categories) { wpsc_categories = {}; }
wpsc_categories['countdown_example1'] = 5;
</script>
<div id="countdown_example1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!wpsc_categories) { wpsc_categories = {}; }
wpsc_categories['countdown_example2'] = 5;
</script>
<div id="countdown_example2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!wpsc_categories) { wpsc_categories = {}; }
wpsc_categories['countdown_example3'] = 5;
</script>
<div id="countdown_example3"></div>
```

As soon as the code in this block is executed by javascript the wpsc_categories variable will be filled with information about the 3 required counters. This information is what `tick()` uses to update the timers.

**Update 2**
My example used `setInterval` inside the `tick()` function, which was bad! as setInterval is a repeating timer, so every call to tick created a new timer and so it would change the time exponentially :D

`setTimeout()` is one-shot, `setInterval()` keeps going till you stop it!

Comment: I just want timer that will work for multiple objects, this function also checks category and edlets it and etc. 

I have written plugin like this for this function, now I only want to write one week countdown for every queried category.

But if using this 
        "delete wpsc_categories[category];" would be safe to use with my wordpress theme, why not?

Comment: okay okay, now I've tested it and works perfect for me, just deleted code where it says to delete that category after countdown finish.

that's a lot. 
just don't understand what this does: 
if (!wpsc_categories) { wpsc_categories = {}; }

Comment: just there should be some error in your code

even on 5 seconds, it goes 5,3,0. on greater seconds it does same but with greater intervals. did you check your code?

Comment: I didn't test all of it no, the delete command and the variable is all javascript and will not delete anything on your server, it just removes the countdown. Did you change anything else? Looks like you might have added another -1 in.

Comment: I recopyed everything. for example for value 10, it starts from 10 -> 8 -> 4 and zero

and my browser goes crazy.

is it possible that my WordPress uses "wpsc_categories" for something else in tick() function?

Comment: I even deleted formatTime function from element.innerHTML = wpsc_categories[category]; and tried in separate html on my server just the code, still counts strange

Comment: as soon as the html is rendered and the javascript starts there is absolutely no interaction with wordpress. wpsc_categories is something I created so unless there is more javascript elsewhere that uses that name i'm not sure what the problem is. do you have a live example i could take a look at? to debug the code

Comment: found a few problems with my code :D like setInterval instead of setTimeout. got a working example here http://jsfiddle.net/Lf7Ku/8/